# iPhone Battery Percentage on OS X (Cocoa) like iTunes

Tags: iphone, macos, cocoa, battery

I'm trying to find a SDK or anything in Cocoa for OS X that will detect when an iPhone is connected and will show the battery percentage of the iPhone just like iTunes where it shows you how much your phone is charged (the little battery icon). So if anyone can tell me if there is something like this i thank you in advance. (BTW this has to be for OS X)

Comment: On cocoa not in an iPhone app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://bitbucket.org/tristero/mobiledeviceaccess
Specifically, getMobileGestaltValue: using the key BatteryCurrentCapacity
That will give you the numeric value you want - displaying it is a different issue.

https://bitbucket.org/tristero/ipodaccessframework is a skeleton application that shows how to monitor for iDevices being connected...

In fact, https://bitbucket.org/tristero/ipodbattery is exactly what you want.

Comment: All dead links now, found this fork of mobiledeviceaccess on GitHub: https://github.com/cipi1965/MobileDeviceAccess

Comment: Looks like it uses the private MobileDevice framework, so not suitable for the AppStore?

Comment: I nuked all the stuff from Bitbucket because they no longer supported Mercurial and I didn't see a lot of value putting it anywhere else since, as you observe, it relies on an internal framework that makes it unsuitable for the App Store.

Comment: You will note that the fork has a single issue that says "doesn't work on ios13" - this stuff is all built on internals that Apple deliberately break from release to release.  They don't want you doing this stuff