# How can I programmatically determine battery health of an Iphone connected via USB

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, usb, battery

== **UPDATED FOR CLARIFICATION** ==

thanks for reading this!

A **MacOS Application** called coconut battery is able to determine the following information:

- total battery capacity at the moment
- design capacity (the original capacity before wear and tear)

of an iPhone connected via USB.

I would like to know how they do it as I couldn't find the information neither in the console nor in the system profiler.

Anyone any idea?

Best,

Fabian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone Battery Percentage on OS X (Cocoa) like iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805987/iphone-battery-percentage-on-os-x-cocoa-like-itunes)

Answer (score -1):

```
if (![[UIDevice currentDevice] isBatteryMonitoringEnabled]){
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
}
NSLog(@"battery : %f", [[UIDevice currentDevice] batteryLevel]);
```

Comment: Hi @MarkBell , thank you for the answer, but I believe it to be incomplete: it is not possible to determine battery capacity (neither design capacity, nor current capacity), but only the current charge.